# Update installed packages without generating Pipfile.lock

Tags: python, pipenv, pipfile

I've read [an article](https://realpython.com/pipenv-guide/) on `Pipenv` to understand some concepts like the purpose of a lock file and I think that I'm having some misconceptions.

It discusses that having a `Pipfile.lock` insures us that we can reproduce the same exact working environment when deploying the application into the production environment without any surprises.

In other words:

> it provides a deterministic builds for your Python project without gaining the responsibility of updating versions of sub-dependencies.

My conception is that with a `Pipfile`, I can update all packages while being certain that I can always bring my working environment back using the `Pipfile.lock`. And if after update everything was working fine I can lock the environment using `pipenv lock`. However I can't seem to find a way to update the packages without re-generating the `Pipfile.lock` and loosing the last working state of the project.

Am I missing something here? Is this workflow wrong?

Comment: How about you use git for that?

Comment: @BojanKogoj Sure... But what I'm actually trying to understand is why the `lock file` does not work as intended; Or if there is something that I'm missing about how `pipenv` does work.

Comment: Lock file works as intended. It's purpose is to prevent server from having different version than user. We had this situation, in "patch" they (library) made a breaking change, and server updated and stopped working. Took me hours to find out what was wrong because it was working locally.